Solving dependencies on Flutter project from Flutter flow code
How can I resolve dependency conflicts when copying code from FlutterFlow?
I am copying code from FlutterFlow that includes the following imports:
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
trying flutter pub add flutterflow:
Because every version of flutter from sdk depends on collection 1.18.0 and every version of flutterflow depends on collection 1.15.0, flutter from sdk is incompatible with flutterflow.

Instead of copying one file's code. Try to download the project's code and you will get the dependencies in pubspec.yaml file.

Free account does not allow dowload code.
